# How to connect Chrome with Android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, vagrant, virtualbox, ionic-framework

I am using Vagrant (Provider - VirtualBox) for developing an Android app with the ionic framework (Angular). I can compile and deploy my ionic app to my USB connected Android device. But how can I connect and debug my app now with Chrome running on my host machine? Because the USB connection is exclusively given to the guest machine (vm). And therefore chrome can only detect it after I have halted my guest machine (vm). How can this be solved?

Comment: Did you tried `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome address ?